# Cant use formGroup.controls['xxx'].setValue('someString');

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Cant use `FormGroup.controls['lable'].setValue('some string');`

My Angular reactive form have FormControls and a FormArray. In method I want to set value at some index of FormArray. I can able to get FormArray and FormGroup at specific Index (b is foormGroup at some index in code). but after i am unable to set value to that FormGroup.

FORM DECLARATION (WORKING)

```
this.addUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    primaryNode: [{lable: '' , uuid: ''},Validators.required],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    roleFormArray: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatPassword: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

ADD FORM IN FORMARRAY(WORKING)

```
roleFormArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      role: ['', Validators.required],
      node: [{lable: '' , uuid: ''}, Validators.required]
    }));
    let a = this.addUserForm.get('roleFormArray');
```

NOT WORKING CODE

In method

```
let b = (<FormGroup((<FormArray>this.addUserForm.controls['roleFormArray']).controls[index]));
```

debugger
//till now b have data as FormGroup

//but this line is not working

```
b.controls['role'].setValue('somevalue');
```

I want to set value to 'role' and 'node'

Comment: You need to mention the index as well, since you are manipulating the array from control.

Comment: As it's a formArray, you should try:
b.controls[i].controls['role'].setValue('somevalue');

Answer (score 1):

As it's a formArray, you could try:

```
  b.controls[index].controls['role'].setValue('somevalue');
```

or:

```
  b.get([index, 'role']).setValue('somevalue');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
  (((<FormArray>this.addUserForm.controls['roleFormArray']).at(someIndex)) as FormGroup).controls['role'].setValue('somestring');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment, You can specify the index of the formgroup inside the formarray and access the formcontrols of that formgroup:

```
b.at(index).controls['role'].setValue('somevalue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.roleFormArray.setValue({
    role: 'value',
    node: 'value',
});
```